# Motor driver current sense does not have the same shape as the sensed current (DRV8874 current mirror)

Tags: motor, analog, integrated-circuit, driver, three-phase

I am using 3x [DRV8874 motor drivers](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8874.pdf?ts=1623734179685&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8874) to drive the 3 windings of a brushless AC motor (OUT1 of each motor driver to each winding, such that the current sensed by each driver is not a combination of multiple currents).

I am driving the motor with the usual 3-phase sine wave pattern and I measured on the oscilloscope that the currents were correctly applied (with current clamps). The motor is turning normally.

However, the motor current sensing I got from these drivers is somewhat not proportional to the current in the corresponding winding: it's closer to a triangle than a sine:

[image]

I looked everywhere in [the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8874.pdf?ts=1623734179685&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8874) and I cannot find anything which would explain this. At first, I thought it could be due to the capacitor I placed in parallel to the IPROPI resistor, but a quick LTspice simulation does not show this behaviour... Perhaps the capacitor is interfering with the current clamp (ITRIP) ? But if so, how - and how to solve it knowing I have to acquire the currents asynchronously?

What is happening?

Parameters for the drivers used:

- VREF = 3.3V
- R IPROPI = 15k (in parallel with 100nF)
- IMODE = GND
- PMODE = Hi-Z
- VM = 12V
- Winding = {12Ohm, 6mH}
- Otherwise identical to the datasheet's Figure 33 (each of the 3 windings connected to OUT1 of each driver, floating neutral):
  [image]

Comment: Please provide a schematic

Comment: You're right that even though I doubt the problem is in it (pretty standard application),  it helps to dive into the topic. I've added it.

Comment: What was the PWM frequency? Can you show us the current clamp waveform?

Comment: @Bruce 30kHz - where ? The current out of the OUT pins is looking good.